# How can I set extended monitor setting as the default when any secondary screen it attached?

Tags: windows-7, windows, external-display, display-settings

When I plug in a new secondary monitor to my laptop, I have to configure the display from "Duplicate" to "Extended". While this persistes if I plug in the *same* screen, windows forgets/ignores this preference every time I connect a *new* screen (I assume it's based on hardware ID).

But I work in a hot desking office, so I connect a new screen virtually every day, and it's pain having to set the same exact settings every time I sit at a new desk.

**How can I set a default display setting for when a new screen is connected?**

By the way, all secondary screens are the same exact model of screen throughout the office, so don't tell me "it's a good idea, because you can't predict the resolution etc", because that "reason" is not relevant.

---

My stuff:

- Windows 7 Enterprise
- Dell Latitude E6430s, which has a 1366 x 768 screen
- External monitors are all Dell 1920 x 1080

Comment: What version of Windows are you running? What is your make and model of laptop? I use a Dell latitude running Windows 10 and move it all over the place on different docks and monitors and never have to change this setting.

Comment: @Appleoddity Windows 7 Ent on Dell Latitude E6430s (added to Q)